# Find Damaged Creeps (or how to debug)

Tags: javascript, screeps

I've tried to program healer creep.
Simple task:

1. find damaged creep.
2. heal damaged creep.
3. if no damaged
   creeps were found, return home (hardcoded Spawn1)

Here is my code (I also tried option with Game.CREEPS but it gave same effect):

```
module.exports = function (creep) {
    var damagedCreeps = creep.room.find(Game.MY_CREEPS, function(chr){return chr.hits < chr.hitsMax;});
    if (damagedCreeps.length > 0){
        creep.moveTo(damagedCreeps[0]);
        creep.heal(damagedCreeps[0]);
    } else {
        creep.moveTo(Game.spawns.Spawn1);
    }
};
```

Here are my creeps (in order of creation):

1. Harvester1 (hits: 300, hitsMax: 300),
2. Harvester2 (hits: 300, hitsMax: 300),
3. Guard1 (hits: 190, hitsMax: 400),
4. Healer1 (hits: 400, hitsMax: 400),
5. Harvester3 (hits: 300, hitsMax: 300).

Harvesters are doing their thing, guard is doing his thing and "Healer1" follows "Harvester1".

I thought that I've misspelled hits and hitsMax and failed to notice it but in console I got:

```
> Game.creeps.Harvester1.hits
< 300
> Game.creeps.Harvester1.hitsMax
< 300
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is that 'chr' parameter contains something else than creep object.

I tried:

1. consol.log(chr) but nothing appeared in in-game Console.
2. 'Game.creeps.Healer1.memory.a=chr; Game.creeps.Healer1.a=chr;' and in console typed 'Game.creeps.Healer1.memory.a'/'Game.creeps.Healer1.a' but got undefined.
3. In Chrome's js console: var a='Healer1'; a.hits < a.hitsMax;. Got 'false' on the second one.

Is it a game bug or have I missed something?

Comment: I know nothing about creeps, but the api reference for Room.find mentions that the second param is an object that can have a property called filter that is a function.  Maybe try `var damagedCreeps = creep.room.find(Game.MY_CREEPS, {filter: function(chr){return chr.hits < chr.hitsMax;}});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

James is correct. You can find your wounded soldiers using

```
var wounded = creep.room.find( Game.MY_CREEPS, {
    filter: function(object) {
        return ( object.hits < object.hitsMax );
    } } );
```

Now you can check if you have any and walk trough the list like

```
if( wounded.length ) {
    // Care for any wounded soldiers
}
```

and

```
for( var i = 0; i < wounded.length; ++i ) {
    // Do something to wounded[i]
}
```

Comment: I clearly misread the documentation. Thank you both, it's working like a charm.

Comment: Protip - if your healer gets hurt, it will get stuck trying to heal itself, so make sure you exclude it!